# Cells with "" value return false when checking with ISBLANK()

Tags: microsoft-excel

I start with a new worksheet and I obviously have cell A1 which is empty. Then, in cell B1, I write:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",A1)
```

Then B1 indeed appears empty. Then, in cell C1, I check:

```
=ISBLANK(B1)
```

and I get `FALSE`.

I then do the following. I copy A1 and paste its value into B2. Then, in cell C2, I check:

```
=ISBLANK(B2)
```

and I get `TRUE`, as expected.

Final step, I copy B1 and paste its value into B3. Then, in cell C3, I check:

```
= ISBLANK(B3)
```

and I get `FALSE`, once more. But when I edit the cell, there's nothing there.

Then I had an idea and I did a final test (in cell D1, copied down to D2, D3):

```
=AND(B1,TRUE())
```

which yields `TRUE` for all 3 cells, as it should do when B1:B3 were blank.

Could anyone please explain what's happening? Is there some way the `TRUE` result of `=if(conditional,"","blah")` is a real blank cell?

-m-

Answer (score 1):

That's the expected behaviour of Excel, to check for both `blank` and `""` (empty string) you can use this formula:

`=IF(A1="",empty,not empty)`

---

> the ISBLANK function returns the logical value TRUE if the value argument is a reference to an **empty cell**; otherwise it returns FALSE.

from [office support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/is-functions-0f2d7971-6019-40a0-a171-f2d869135665)

If you have a formula in a cell then it can not be empty anymore. You can set the output of the formula to be an empty string ("") which appears to be blank on the screen, that can be tested by above formula.

Comment: Thank you, though I am not really sure what is the expected behaviour of Excel. How would the formula change anything? I used it in my tests and the results are more or less the same. And most importantly: Is there then any way to return a real blank cell from a function? One that `ISBLANK()` returns `TRUE` for?

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: Thank you for the edit, this is something that I can now perfectly understand. Funny, after 25 years of on and off using Excel, it still took me a couple of seconds to fully realise what you meant by "If you have a formula in a cell then it can not be empty anymore.".